# The name 'Email' does not exist in current context (Web App)

Tags: c#, web, sitefinity

I'm in the middle of converting my sitefinity website project to a web application.

We have a user control that was working originally on the website but now we are getting the following error when building the web app.

The name 'Email' does not exist in current context (line 104)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Net.Mail;
using Telerik.Sitefinity.Security;
using Telerik.Sitefinity.Security.Model;
using Telerik.Sitefinity.Model;


namespace UserControls.Saville
{

    public partial class CustomUserRegistration : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Request.Url.Query.Contains("?registered"))
            {
                userRegistration.Visible = false;
                RegSuccess.Text = "We have emailed you an account activation link. Please check your emails.";
            }
        }

        protected void btnRegister_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Match emailValid = Regex.Match(tbxRegEmail.Text, @"^(([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+|([a-zA-Z]{1}|[\w-]{2,}))@"
                                                                + @"((([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\.([0-1]?
                                                            [0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\."
                                                                + @"([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\.([0-1]?
                                                            [0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])){1}|"
                                                                + @"([a-zA-Z]+[\w-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,4})$");
            if (tbxFirstName.Text != String.Empty &&
                tbxSurname.Text != String.Empty &&
                tbxJobTitle.Text != String.Empty &&
                tbxOrganisation.Text != String.Empty &&
                tbxTelephone.Text != String.Empty &&
                tbxAddressLine1.Text != String.Empty &&
                tbxAddressCity.Text != String.Empty &&
                tbxAddressPostcode.Text != String.Empty &&
                tbxAddressCounty.Text != String.Empty &&
                tbxAddressCountry.Text != String.Empty &&
                tbxRegEmail.Text != String.Empty &&
                tbxRegUsername.Text != String.Empty &&
                tbxRegPassword.Text != String.Empty &&
                tbxCPassword.Text != String.Empty &&
                emailValid.Success &&
                tbxRegPassword.Text.Length > 5 &&
                tbxRegPassword.Text == tbxCPassword.Text)
            {
                var manager = UserManager.GetManager("AspNetSqlMembershipProvider");
                manager.Provider.SuppressSecurityChecks = true;

                if (manager.UserExists(tbxRegUsername.Text))
                {
                    RegError.Text = "Username already in use.";
                }
                else
                {
                    if (manager.EmailExists(tbxRegEmail.Text))
                    {
                        RegError.Text = "Email Address is already registered";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MembershipCreateStatus status;
                        User user = manager.CreateUser(tbxRegUsername.Text, tbxRegPassword.Text, tbxRegEmail.Text, "Question", "Answer", false, null, out status);

                        manager.SaveChanges();

                        if (status == MembershipCreateStatus.Success)
                        {
                            UserProfileManager profileManager = UserProfileManager.GetManager();
                            profileManager.Provider.SuppressSecurityChecks = true;

                            SitefinityProfile userProfile = profileManager.CreateProfile(user, Guid.NewGuid(), typeof(SitefinityProfile)) as SitefinityProfile;
                            if (userProfile != null)
                            {
                                userProfile.SetValue("Title", ddlTitle.SelectedItem.Text);
                                userProfile.FirstName = tbxFirstName.Text;
                                userProfile.LastName = tbxSurname.Text;
                                userProfile.SetValue("JobTitle", tbxJobTitle.Text);
                                userProfile.SetValue("Organisation", tbxOrganisation.Text);
                                userProfile.SetValue("MainPhone", tbxTelephone.Text);
                                userProfile.SetValue("MobilePhone", tbxMobileTelephone.Text);
                                userProfile.SetValue("Address_Street_1", tbxAddressLine1.Text);
                                userProfile.SetValue("Address_Street_2", tbxAddressLine2.Text);
                                userProfile.SetValue("Address_City", tbxAddressCity.Text);
                                userProfile.SetValue("Address_PostcodeZIP", tbxAddressPostcode.Text);
                                userProfile.SetValue("Address_CountyState", tbxAddressCounty.Text);
                                userProfile.SetValue("Address_Country", tbxAddressCountry.Text);
                                userProfile.SetValue("Registration_Code", tbxRegCode.Text);
                                userProfile.SetValue("SendMarketing", chkbxMaterials.Checked);
                                profileManager.SaveChanges();

                                RoleManager roleManager = RoleManager.GetManager("AspNetSqlRoleProvider");
                                roleManager.Provider.SuppressSecurityChecks = true;
                                Role untrained = roleManager.GetRole("Untrained");
                                roleManager.AddUserToRole(user, untrained);

                                roleManager.SaveChanges();

                                String emailContent = String.Format("{1}, <br/><br/>Your registration is nearly complete.<br/><br/>Please follow this link to activate your account:<br/><a href='{2}/login?ID={3}'>{2}/login?ID={3}</a>", Environment.NewLine, tbxFirstName.Text, Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority), user.Id.ToString());
                                Email.Send(tbxRegEmail.Text, "support.manager@*****.com", "*****", emailContent);

                                Response.Redirect("~/login?registered");
                            }

                            RegError.Text = "An error occurred whilst registering. If problem persists please contact support.manager@*****.com";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                RegError.Text = "Please check all required fields have been filled and are valid.";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Originally we had an Email.cs file within a different folder within the project, but the webapp cannot seem to locate this.

Comment: add a fully quilified name for Email class like Mynamespace.Email.Send(.....)

Comment: Unfortunately I have already tried this but we then just get the same error but this time for the 'MYnamespace'.Email.Send(...

Comment: Just to sure: Have you verified that the namespace for Email (in `Email.cs`) is correct, and that the class is public?

Comment: is your class is accessible.?

Comment: Yes, namespace in Email.cs is correct and public. Yes its accessible :|

Comment: Is the Email.cs file actually part of the solution or just sitting on disk?  Web App don't automatically include everything that is in the project folder like Web Site projects do.

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for the help, I figured it out. When converting a website to a webapp I had to compile the email.cs instead of leaving it within 'content'. Something soo simple, yet I couldnt find the answer for ages!

Answer (score 1):

Might I recommend a slightly different solution for sending the email. Use a `MailDefinition` and `MailMessage` class to create the body of the email and then from there use the `EmailSender` class along with the SMTP settings in Sitefinity to send the email. Sample code below:

```
using System.Net.Mail;
using Telerik.Sitefinity.Services;
using Telerik.Sitefinity.Web.Mail;
using Telerik.Sitefinity.Configuration;

var smtpSettings = Config.Get<SystemConfig>().SmtpSettings;
MailDefinition mailDef = new MailDefinition()
{
    IsBodyHtml = true,
    BodyFileName = "~/Files/EmailBody.html",
    Subject = "Thanks for Commenting!",
    From = !smtpSettings.DefaultSenderEmailAddress.IsNullOrEmpty() ?  smtpSettings.DefaultSenderEmailAddress : smtpSettings.UserName
};
MailMessage email = mailDef.CreateMailMessage(this.EmailControl.Value.ToString(), new ListDictionary(), this);
EmailSender.Get().Send(email);
```

The `ListDictionary` is being used to replace values in the body with values from your code. If you don't need that, you can just include a empty dictionary.

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for the help, I figured it out. When converting a website to a webapp I had to compile the email.cs instead of leaving it within 'content'. Something soo simple, yet I couldnt find the answer for ages!